# Как переопределить путь скрипта в html?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css

Всем привет.Столкнулся с следующей проблемой:Есть приложение на C#, которая создаёт локальный html файл.В папке приложения С#, лежат файлы с css и скрпитами(Они слишком массивные, чтобы просто вписать их в html). Каким способом можно переопределить путь для этих файлов,если я перекину html на другой ПК(учитывая ,что на нем есть это приложение с#)?

Comment: пути относительные задавайте, `source="script.js"`, браузер будет брать файл из текущей папки, где лежит html файл

Comment: В этом и проблема,что файл не будет лежать в одно папке с скриптами

Comment: тогда я не понимаю, что вы спрашиваете и где что будет лежать

Comment: Скрипты и стили лежат в папке приложения С#,а т.к. пользователь может сохранить файл html в абсолютно любое место,то для указания пути я использую абсолютный путь, соответственно при передачи файла на другой ПК(на котором тоже есть приложение С#) путь становится неверным, и суть вопроса в том ,как можно переопределить путь(причем на ПК 2 абсолютый путь нам неизвестен) или другое рабочее решение,которого я возможно не вижу

Comment: Ну можете поднять [http сервер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A373567+tcplistener) и вообще обойтись без файлов, которые надо перекладывать. В файловом режиме возможности браузера ограничены.